# How to get model status in tensorflow serving

Tags: java, scala, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm tring to write a client in Scala (or Java) to get model status in tensorflow serving. After reading through all the proto files in the directory: */serving/tensorflow_serving/apis*, I thought these two files: ***get_model_status.proto*** and ***model_service.proto*** provide the necessary apis for me to use. But my simple test returned with an error: ***"Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED"***. And here is the code snippet:

```
val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
    .forAddress(host, port)
    .usePlaintext(true)
    .asInstanceOf[ManagedChannelBuilder[_]]
    .build
val modelStub = tensorflow.serving.ModelServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel)
val modelRequest = tensorflow.serving.GetModelStatus
    .GetModelStatusRequest
    .newBuilder
    .setModelSpec(ModelSpec.newBuilder.setName("x").setSignatureName("x"))
    .build
println(modelStub
    .getModelStatus(modelRequest)
    .getModelVersionStatusList
    .asScala)
```

The error "UNIMPLEMENTED" seems to suggest that I have to define a new signature to add to the meta graph to process the request and return the response, which confuses me because this new signature is not the model I want to check anymore. My question is how to use this `getModelStatus` function? Any advices are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Answer my own question:

1. the above code is correct;
2. no need to define extra signature, just use normally exported model;
3. using tf_serving version >= 1.5 solves this problem.

The "UNIMPLEMENTED" error came out when I used tf_serving binary of version 1.4.

For more details about this process, you could check the official python function ***testGetModelStatus*** in ***/serving/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server_test.py***